# "Title Case" or "Sentence case"?

Tags: discussion, title

Does Stack Overflow prefer title case or sentence case?

Here's an example of title case:

```
Titles: Title Case or Sentence Case?
```

Here's an example of sentence case:

```
Titles: title case or sentence case?
```

I use title case because that's how it was taught in school (and I definitely don't use cell-phone case). But I've had others edit my questions to sentence case. And I just came across an edit to title case ([Calculate the Number of Weeks in a Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353703/calculate-the-number-of-weeks-in-a-month)).

I realize this is close to a waste of time and not worth enforcement energy. But I am curious what the site prefers (or if there's a policy).

Comment: If the title is a sentence (especially if it has full punctuation), you'd probably want sentence case. If it's *not* a complete sentence, you'd probably want title case. But that's just the way *I* was taught.

Comment: Sentence, please.

Comment: and don't tag in the title it is equivalent to spam

Comment: [Never tag in the title!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/148287)

Comment: As a non-native speaker of English, I absolutely *detest* Title Case, which I consider highly unreadable. But probably that's just because my native language is German, where there's a mix of upper-case and lower-case initial characters, with a bias towards the latter.

Comment: Very much related, on MSE (where duplicates of this very MSO question live as well): [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) And on English.SE: [How Should Titles Be Capitalized?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/how-should-titles-be-capitalized/1997#1997)

Comment: @Arjan - Shog's answer is interesting. Perhaps the site needs to change the label's text from *Title* to *Summary* (the label next to the text box after clicking *Ask Question*).

Comment: @stakx - This is where my American ignorance kicks in... Is it just German, or do other languages have the same properties such that other speakers would feel the same.

Comment: Being Dutch, I even dislike how German upper cases too many words. So yes, I agree with @stakx.

Comment: These days we are happy when the title consists of a series of almost coherent english words.

Comment: Title case used to be popular in English as a mark of formal writing, but that fashion has changed a lot now (some forms would capitalise the 'Or' in your example too). I suspect it carries on in Indian English, which is why many Indian programmers new to Stack Overflow use this style.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I never even heard of something called title case.

Comment: MSE duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98066/238586

Comment: @cerbus that was the joke... :/

Comment: I was wondering where was your school, in the US?

Answer (score 85):

Sentence case.

And:

- **Capitalize names like Java, Apache, C++, etc. identical to how the names are actually capitalized**

  So, take Java, for example. Since the language name is "Java", it should be:

  > How does Java foo the bar?

  **Not**:

  > How does java foo the bar?

  And **definitely not**:

  > How does JAVA foo the bar?

  "MATLAB", for example, is actually ALL CAPS, so making it all caps would be appropriate. Although many probably use "Matlab" instead and/or detest all caps, so there is something to be said for using that instead (although others possibly detest incorrect capitalization).
- **Things that should be lower case should remain lower case if at the beginning of titles**

  Don't make the title sentence case if that would involve changing the case of some case-sensitive thing (like a language construct) to something that it's not supposed to be, like `int` (wrt. Java or C++) to `Int` for example. Ideally the title should be modified such that it no longer starts with `int`, or replace it with a word meaning the same, i.e. change `struct` to `Structure` or `int` to `Integer`, if that would be fine (which it may not be in Java, for example, as `Integer` is a different type than `int`).

  If this is not possible, I'd suggest keeping it lower case.
- **Try to make your title an actual question**

  For example:

  > Is title case or sentence case better?
- **Have the title be specific**

  Don't ask:

  > How do I foo the bar?

  When you actually want to know one of these:

  > How do I foo the bar in O(n) time?
  >   Which of these is a better way to foo the bar?
  >   Why isn't my code to foo the bar working?
  >   How do I do this marginally related thing inside my code to foo the bar?
  >   etc.
- **[Don't try to force tags into the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/148287)**

  So:

  > Is title case or sentence case better?

  **Not**:

  > Titles: Is title case or sentence case better?

  Some may say that "in titles" should be appended above, and some may not. I tend towards not adding it, as it's redundant with the tags, but, on the other hand, it makes the title more self-contained, so I won't always edit it out of titles.
- **Try to keep your title to a single sentence**

  **Not** like: (arbitrarily chosen conforming Hot Network question)

  > Playing large video files over wireless network. What technical specification should I look for when buying wireless router?

  But rather more like:

  > Which technical specifications are important in a wireless router with regard to streaming large videos?

Comment: You give guidance here but what is the reasoning? *Why* is this policy the right way?

Comment: @usr I think the first two points can pretty much fall under not calling things what they're not. The tags in title could lead to redundancy in the page title - you can get something like "java - Java: ..." (and redundancy elsewhere, like in the question lists). Beyond that, these types of answers are largely opinion-based and you upvote or downvote based on agreement, and sufficiently many upvotes essentially becomes the new official policy.

Comment: Make your title an actual question? I find those annoying. "How do I foo the bar?" is longer than "Fooing the bar".

Comment: [tag:MATLAB] regular here. I detest "Matlab". (also can't stand the fact that the tag gets lower-case'd, but you can't win 'em all)

Comment: @bjb568 Personal preference, I guess.

Comment: I always adhere to the capitalization used in the tag info page, therefore: [MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/info). And ironically, in the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648) to the question [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647), **number 4** reads: **"Don't start with "How do I..."** Finally, where language elements appear in a title, I believe it is helpful to surround them with quotes (I prefer single quotes): **'int'**

Comment: It's JavaScript, not Javascript, not Java Script, not javaScript, not javascript, and kittens cry if you type JAVASCRIPT (sorry Mr. Bigglesworth). JS is permitted, as is js, on rare occasions. But really, you're likely talking about ECMAScript :P.