# Flagging post as duplicate should produce comment with initial capital letter

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, automatic-comments

When flagging a post as a duplicate, a comment is posted in your account name:

> possible duplicate of *A StackOverflow Question*

Grammatically `possible` should be `Possible`. What are the chances of this being changed?

Also, I do realize how facetious this post is.

Comment: The chances are somewhere between [slim and nil](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for that link. There's always a chance - we just need to complain more.

Comment: [We have hope!](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DzMRrNY0pxfM&ei=9JphU-CbPKblyQGjkYCADg&usg=AFQjCNGgpfxwcNbU-aNS5sDMI5RctCWPvQ&sig2=2CWIv1qgb5I9dBTpjNqO0g&bvm=bv.65636070,d.aWc)

Comment: So I guess this is a ...

Comment: This question may already have an answer on [Flagging post as duplicate should produce comment with initial capital letter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253054/2888561)

Comment: How is this question (asked a year ago) a duplicate of one which was asked yesterday?

Answer (score -3):

Technically, the comment is a *fragment* instead of a *complete sentence*.  Thus, there is no need to capitalize the first letter nor should it be capitalized.  The comment as a whole would need to be changed in order for this to make sense.

However, you can edit the comment (I'm pretty sure) in order to make it appear however you would like.  It is most likely presented in this way because a complete sentence is not necessary to convey to message and just seems tedious.

Also, the quality of the comment grammar-wise is the decision of those who make the site and reflects on the site quality.  Other fragments that may be capitalized on the site are entirely the decision of the poster and do not reflect on the site's ability to properly use grammar.

Comment: Neither are the titles of most questions complete sentences, but we capitalize the initial letter there.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Titles are capitalized in English such as titles of books, but a comment is not a title.

Comment: Titles in English use title case; here [we use sentence case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/title-case-or-sentence-case).

Comment: True, but titles of questions *may* be sentences (not necessarily complete sentences).  But, overall, it just seems like an entirely different set of circumstances.  Plus, that does not reflect the quality of the actual *site's grammar*.  It represents the grammar skills of the poster.

Comment: Like this comment?

Comment: @KeithThompson See the updated answer.