# How do I handle an answer covering a lot more than what the question asks?

Tags: discussion, meta

I recently answered this **Meta** question regarding the case in titles - [Title Case or Sentence Case?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/#252687)

I started off just answering the question, but between noting special cases, things specific to OP's scenario and one or two other things that came to mind, it's more of a generic best-practices for titles now.

What should I do here?

- I figured it might significantly increase its future value if I were to edit the question to instead ask about best practices for titles. Would such a significant change to the question be appropriate?

  I thought I'd edit the question in such a way to keep "Is title case or sentence case better?" as part of the question body, specifically for searchability ... if that makes a difference.
- Should I perhaps move this into a different question (either modifying the original answer, keeping it as is, or replacing it) (losing the +49/-0, showing fairly significant agreement with what was said there)?
- Or should I just leave it as is?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't edit the question so radically like that.  If you feel that that more general question is worth having around, then ask a new question that is more general.  If you do, consider editing the answer on the older question to remove some of the tangential information (possibly just linking to the new answer) to keep it more on point.

This is particularly the case because the more specific question is still a problem/question that other people have and will search for, in addition to the broader question.  If the narrower question was so narrow that nobody would ever search on it or be in that same position, then you could consider editing the existing question to generalize it a bit.

Comment: I thought I'd edit the question in such a way to keep "Is title case or sentence case better?" as part of the question body, specifically for searchability ... if that would change anything.

Comment: @Dukeling I still see that as too radical of a change, especially for a question that's already entirely appropriate.  I could possibly justify a radical change to a question that is so bad it'd need to be deleted if not saved, but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: I think this conflicts with [Joel's advice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) - "It is OK to edit a question to make it more general".

Comment: @Dukeling The problem is that, in this case, editing the question to make it more general can make it *less* useful, because there are likely to be people searching for an answer to that specific question, and generalizing the question can make it *harder* for people to find that answer.  While editing a question to make it more general isn't globally wrong, I don't consider it globally right either.  If you did, why did you bother asking this meta question.