# Proper Etiquette for Editing a Post that was Already Edited

Tags: discussion, edits

Since I hit the 2k rep limit and was able to just edit posts at will, the edit review queue was something I tried to frequent.  I have started giving up on it, since I will see a ton of posts that are edited quickly, normally by a lower rep user trying to gain points.  My normal action has been to use `Improve` and correct the glaring issues still wrong with the post, blatant capitalization errors, huge grammar mistakes, and sometimes just adding words here or there to make the post fluid and readable.

The problem is that I have seen issues where these changes, since they are correct in some way, are quickly getting approved.  I then get about halfway through an edit and see the popup "Someone has edited this post 1 time" or something along those lines, letting me know the edit went through.  I then have to try and save my edits, open new windows, and jump around to continue editing the post that clearly needed improving.

**When editing that post properly, what is the correct way to handle earlier and smaller edits?  Should I be trying to roll back to the original post in some way?  Do I just leave it so that user gets their 2 points for very minimal effort?**  It is super frustrating seeing that user's activity and seeing a large number of similar "lower quality" edits just quickly changing minor things looking for fast rep.

Not trying to call anyone out, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955570/serialize-a-java-myownobject-in-hadoop) is the post I am refering to.

Comment: The "Someone has edited this post 1 time" when improving is a pain in the arse (especially since it happens basically every time), and AFAIK there's no particularly nice way of dealing with it. You could I suppose, hit improve, make a partial improvement, mark as helpful/unhelpful and submit. Then go to the post and fully edit it in the 5 minute window.

Comment: @OGHaza maybe I should change this to a feature request, for some way to deal with that.  I understand why that is there, to notify you someone already did work and you don't have to.  But when that edit is minor and still needs work, it's super frustrating (especially with the growing number of minor edits).

Comment: +1 for wanting to improve questions. A minor point, but since you are an editor, I believe the community [prefers sentence case for titles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252624/472495).

Comment: @halfer that is great to find.  I had always wondered that myself.  Good to know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I agree, it can be really annoying. But unfortunately, there's no real solution to this problem. It is not entirely bad though — this prevents a minor edit from overwriting the previous one.

When I'm editing this post and receive this notification, I just copy the entire markdown get out of the edit pane and check the revision history of the post to see if the previous editor covered all the problems with the post. If they didn't, I'd click on the "Edit" button again and paste the markdown I copied before. Frustrating, I know.

> Should I be trying to roll back to the original post in some way?

No, that's pointless. AFAIK, rolling back a previously approved edit does not affect the reputation of the person who suggested the edit. The editor wouldn't even get notified of the rollback and they'd just continue making similar edits.

In this particular case, the person who suggested the edit did not address all the issues in the post. Honestly, I don't think it is the editors that's the problem. It's the people who approve these "too minor" edits that are a problem.

If you notice someone who is making a lot of poor-quality edits, you could try to @-ping them in  the comments under one of the questions and politely request them to address all the issues in the post (and optionally link to the [Help Center article on Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and/or [Meta FAQ post on Editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/220538)).

Related feature requests:

- [Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning)
- [Why doesn't the "this post has already been edited" dialog allow you to continue overriding anyways?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121241/why-doesnt-the-this-post-has-already-been-edited-dialog-allow-you-to-continue)

Comment: I do the same, + I have had success @pinging problem editors  in the past (though I've rarely resorted to it) and 100% of the time they have no idea they're doing anything wrong since of course the reviewers are consistently approving their edits.

Comment: It stopping minor edits over real one makes sense for lower rep.  Is there maybe a way it knows the person trying to edit is over that 2k edit limit and takes precedence?  If the user editing has full edit rights and the edit that went through was from someone without, maybe ignore that?  The copy/paste works, it's just growing more and more frustrating as low quality approvals are quickly pushed through the queue.

Comment: `Unfortunately, there's no real solution to this problem.`  Sure there is; there's a well-understood solution to this problem.  In programming, this problem is a well-defined issue known as "a race condition", and the solution is to use a lock to prevent concurrent write access to a shared resource.  Have a look at how TVTropes handles this problem for a good example of a working implementation.

Comment: @MasonWheeler This is a more specific problem than race condition, named edit conflict. One way to deal with it is avoid edit conflicts at all (using locking, which in turn introduces trouble with abandoned locks and lock timeouting). Another way is merging changes. MediaWiki lets you do the merge fully manually (two textareas with two versions), Git can solve parallel edits even to one file, if they are on different lines, and offers manual resolving of the conflict by introducing conflict markers otherwise. I like Git’s way the best.

Comment: @Palec: Yeah, like I said, check out the TVTropes implementation.  When you go to edit something, you get a lock which gets canceled if you leave the page, or times out after 20 minutes if you don't finish your edit before then.  And TVTropes articles can be *enormous*; around here a 5-minute lock would probably suffice.