# Unknowingly Editing an Edited Post

Tags: discussion, edits

It is very annoying for me when I am editing a question or answer, click "Save Edits", and get the message telling me that the post had already been edited while I was in the middle of doing *my* edits. I sometimes spend a couple of minutes writing my edits, since I don't generally like making small 5-second edits such as formatting, and so it is frustrating seeing that work go to waste when I suddenly discover that I cannot submit my edits.

It seems to me like it is somewhat difficult to actually make good, meaningful edits because if you take too long to make your edit, someone will beat you to it and you will not be able to submit yours.

Is there a solution to this problem? Am I just doing it wrong?

What do others think about this?

(By the way, I have less than 2k rep. I don't know if this matters.)

Edit: I just found another meta question, [Proper Etiquette for Editing a Post that was Already Edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256768/proper-etiquette-for-editing-a-post-that-was-already-edited), but the premise in that question is that the asker *does* recieve popups stating that edits have been made by other users. However, I do not recieve any of those popups. My edits are just declined when I submit them.

Comment: I tend to `ctrl+A, ctrl+C` just before submitting - gives me the option of just pasting my edit over the top, if the other person's edit is just a subset of what I did.

Comment: At the time of the posting, the asker has less than 2K.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is there a solution to this problem?

Not currently (unless you have a suggestion) besides deal with it

> Am I just doing it wrong?

Nope

> What do others think about this?

It sucks when you spend time on an edit and someone edits it quicker with an inferior edit. Then you have to look at their edit and fix what they missed or edited inappropriately.

> (By the way, I have less than 2k rep. I don't know if this matters.)

The only thing that matters here is that your edits go into a queue for approval. Once you get to 2k then you can unilaterlly make those edits.

**One last note:**

> I don't generally like making small 5-second edits such as formatting

Kudos to you for that! Keep it up!

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow 'lock out' other potential editors when there is an active edit in progress? Or would this potentially lead to undesirable behaviour?

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica I'm sure there is. Set a flag or something. But that may take a schema change and other things (you'd likely need a timeout time for example). Not a bad idea but I don't know the feasibility but you could suggest it.