# Knowing whether a post has been edited and pending approval

Tags: support, edits

Every once in a while, when I see a post that can be approved, I edit it.
Sometimes, after I finish editing and click `save edits`, it says:

[image: message]

When I'm viewing a post, is there a way to know whether it has been edited and waiting approval so that I won't put some more time editing it myself?

**Can't it alert me once it was saved by another user**?

In the last few days I encounter this a lot!

I already read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266295/unknowingly-editing-an-edited-post), and wondered if something has changed since.

One more issue is rejecting due to conflict with subsequent edit (we both ended up with the same version)

[image]

Any tips on how to avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: The edit likely *wasn't* pending when you *started* editing.

Comment: You cannot even start editing the post if there is an edit pending already, so the edit suggestion was submitted after you started your edit.

Comment: @TZHX you are right, I edited my question