# A subsequent change to a question while editing it might result in a seemingly meaningless edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

Yesterday I stumbled upon a question which contained an non-indented block of code, resulting in an incorrect rendering of the latter. I submitted an edit suggestion that would fix the problem, but *during* this the post has already been edited by someone else.

It turned out that those changes were compatible with mine (e.g. the same indenting of the code block), resulting in an edit suggestion that did not  really improve the readability of the question (anymore). I only realised this after submitting my edit, but was not able to retract/update it at that point.

As a result my edit suggestion was rejected by the first reviewer and I can totally understand why. The reviewer did not see the difference from the revision of the question when I started editing it, but rather from the latest revision at the time I submitted my changes.

Is there a mechanism way to avoid such situations? I would really like my edits to be helpful and I definitely don't want to submit trivial spammy edits (that also incurs some kind of a scoring penalty, right?).

There is a similar question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266295/unknowingly-editing-an-edited-post), describing the race conditions, but does not completely answer my question. Could this perhaps be avoided by simply showing the reviewers the set of changes from the revision that was active *when the editing has started*? FWIW, I did not see any notification messages the OP in the linked question mentions.

For the reference, I am posting the links to [my submitted edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10026110) and to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33415808/revisions) of the edited question (I editing the very first revision).

P.S.: Just to avoid any misunderstanding, there was another set of changes applied just minutes later, resulting in my edit suggestion being rejected by the Community bot due to a conflict, but that is not the focus of the question here.

Comment: You should get a notice at the top of the question that the question was edited.  Check for that before submitting.