# What's the etiquette on modifying a post when it already has pending changes?

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm referring to this post, which I've marked as duplicate, downvoted, commented and added changes:
[How to make a Facebook Messenger-like notification like this in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015971/how-to-make-facebook-messenger-like-notification-like-this-in-android/20015985#20015985)

So I added the changes:

> Original credit for this answer in '13
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/15980900/1740059

However, another user edited the post with a number of misspellings:

> Full details of this soluction is avaialble here ->
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/15980900/1740059

What's the convention/etiquette here? My revision is clearly before his in the revision history, yet it's the same change, but with their name. I'm inclined to revert their change, but I wanted to ask here first.

This is similar to *[Proper Etiquette for Editing a Post that was Already Edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256768/proper-etiquette-for-editing-a-post-that-was-already-edited)*.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to know why you did *your* edit in the first place.

From what I can see of the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20015985/revisions), it started as a rather bad link-only answer, which then evolved to include the pertinent bits from that link into its answer.

From *there*, not much else has improved.  For example, no one bothered to see if the link was still around (it's not).

From what I can see, two people answered similar questions in nearly the exact same way, so this smells like a duplicate more than anything else.  You should have flagged it as a duplicate instead of bothering with any sort of editing.

It's tough to talk about etiquette in a context in which an edit shouldn't have happened, which means this probably isn't the answer you wanted to read.  But, there are steps that need to be taken, and the most important one is to determine if an edit like *that* is warranted at all.

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate before I edited it anyway, then did it again to be sure. Not so sure that it's a good idea for people to copy + paste answers from other sources on SO and leave the original answer (8 months prior) uncredited. The question should have been marked as duplicate back then and locked.

Comment: As for the reason as to why, it was because the question was a duplicate and the answer for that question was copied from the original answer, including updates mentioned by other posters in the comments section.

Comment: Exacerbating the fact that it was copied from somewhere on Stack Overflow by putting attribution in the question isn't as helpful as closing it as a dupe.  It's definitely one that flew under the radar, but the edit really only opened a wound there.  Flagging to close would have been the best option; if it seemed like it was a word-for-word rip from the earlier answer, flagging for moderator attention explaining that would be appropriate too.

Comment: it did, and I said that in the comments section, and the author claimed same source, yet it was pretty much lifted with the "oh and do this as well"