# Silly capitalization edit in question title

Tags: discussion, edits, title

I notice that someone has edited the title of my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3680876/revisions
The text "to retrieve direct children" was edited so it now reads "to Retrieve Direct Children". Why was this done?

Comment: Umm........ edit rep?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit 195K - I don't think they did it for the rep...

Comment: And it was not silly - They also improved the formatting of your post, so they improved it

Comment: "I don't like nor understand an edit so I'll call it silly first", do you really want an answer to your question or do you just want to voice your disagreement by being rude ?

Comment: It doesn't look improved to me:(   Does 'Retrieve Direct Children' have a commonly-used 'RDC' acronym?  If not, why the added caps?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit agree on the capitalization of last 3 words being superfluous. The fix `use` on `Using` does make sense to me. But I don't think anyone else than the editor can answer, commenting under the post and pinging the editor would be a better course of action than raising a Meta for this.

Comment: Is using capitalisation in title a crime for op? Because none of this question ever start with a capital...

Comment: @DragandDrop my C and C++ compilers certainly think so:)

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't see how [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3680876/3) is better than [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3680876/2) then just revert it back. But the fact is that that edit improved the readability of the question, with better formatting of the code (Selectors in the middle of the sentences), and splitting it to paragraphs

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm sure you're right about that, but OP is moaning about the caps specifically, not other aspects of the edit.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Then what EricAya wrote seems to be the answer to that - But the overall of the edit was improving the post, and if the OP believe that it's silly then they can always edit back the capitalization (Which seem fine, but I'm not sure as I'm a non-native English speaker)

Comment: You Know, It's Actually Possible For You To Edit It Again To Change The Capitalization Back To The Way You Want It While Keeping The Rest Of The Edits (Which Everyone Seems To Agree Were Helpful).

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: No, "direct children" itself is a nonsensical phrase anyway.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes_that_would_be_a_good_idea.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/title-case-or-sentence-case

Comment: Oh my, what have I done...

Answer (score 18):

[Sampson's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3680876/revisions), considered overall, ***massively*** improves the quality and presentation of the question. So, I have a bit of a problem with the tone and nature of this Meta question, implying that the edit was "silly", pointless, or done merely for selfish reasons.

As has been pointed out, Sampson doesn't benefit in any tangible way from making edits to other people's posts, as he has [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Now, if you really are just asking about why he chose to capitalize the words in the title, that's pretty easy to explain. This is known as [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Title_case) and is, as the name suggests, a common casing convention for titles in the English language. Some style guides encourage it for titles/headings, while others don't use it. Stack Overflow doesn't have an official policy on this, so no one can really say whether Sampson's stylistic choice was objectively right or wrong.

The argument in favor of title case is basically that it's conventional in the English language and many finer publications. The argument against title case is generally that it harms readability (capital letters being harder to read than lowercase letters). I also understand that title case is not used in many European countries, even in English-language publications, so this format tends to rub wrong our users who hail from these locales.

Note that there wouldn't *be* an argument about this if titles were written as full sentences—you know, like *actual questions*. Then, [sentence case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Sentence_case) would obviously be appropriate. This would not only be maximally readable, but it would also provide a better summary of the question.

On balance, though, even if you stylistically disapprove of title case, there is absolutely nothing wrong with this edit. It should not be rolled back, nor should Meta be used as a platform to cast [shade](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shade) upon it.